# Make Columns all Null Pyspark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking to make a list of columns all null. These columns might or might not have values within them. Ideally I am trying to wipe the columns clean of data.

This is what I currently have tried:

```
    null_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    for cols in null_cols:
        df = (
            df.withColumn(cols, F.when(F.col(cols).isNotNull(), F.lit(None)))
        )
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have the `when` statement here because you don't care if there is already data in the column or not, just overwrite it with `None`. Just do

```
null_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for col in null_cols:
    df = df.withColumn(col, F.lit(None))
```

Of course these columns must be nullable, which I assume here.

Comment: If these columns aren't nullable? Why would that even be a thing? Constraints?

Comment: Well, if the columns aren't nullable you can't set the values to null. So the code above would result in an error. But nullable columns is the default. You can check with `df.printSchema()` what the constraints on your columns is. Having nullable columns can make sense since null is always a special case and some functions might not work on columns containing nulls.

Comment: I meant: having not-nullable columns can make sense, e.g. consider calculating the mean. How should a null be handled? Should it be ignored? Should it return a Null too? If you don't want to think about these special cases and don't consider these valid in your data you can just add the `not nullable` constraint to your schema

Comment: Hmm thanks! How would I iterate through printSchema() for only the columns above?

Comment: test = df.schema.json()

Comment: That's a solution. Why would you like to iterate over the schema?

Comment: I am only interested in certain properties and thus want to narrow down the pritnSchema return. The json method worked nicely!